# AuthStateChange React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying see if there is a user with firebase but every time I login into my app and `console.log` the user it says that there is no user and I can't log into my app.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import SignUp from './components/Authentication/SignUp';

import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import Feed from './components/Feed/Feed';

import Search from './components/SearchUser/Search';

import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile';

import Header from './components/Header/Header';

import firebase from './util/firebase';

class App extends Component
 {
 
constructor(){

   super();

   this.state={
     user:''
   }

 } 


 componentDidMount(){

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      this.setState({
        user:user
      })
      // ...
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
      // ...
    }
  });
 }
  
  render(){

    const {user}=this.state;

    console.log(user);

    return(

      <div>
          {
           user?(
             <Router>
               <Header/>
                <Switch>
                   <Route exact path="/feed">
                       <Feed user={user}/>
                   </Route>
                   <Route path="/search">
                       <Search/>
                   </Route>
                   <Route path="/profile">
                       <Profile/>
                   </Route>
                </Switch>
             </Router>
           ):(
             <SignUp/>
           )
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the part where you log in users? Or, at least check that log in is happening and an error is not thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: there is no user because react is rendering the component before onAuthStateChanged's changes in your state so when it renders user is null.

Solution: (Probably not the best approach):

show the fall back UI while it's updating the State.

I'm sharing my solution by changing your code.

It worked for me when I faced the same issue.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import SignUp from './components/Authentication/SignUp';

import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import Feed from './components/Feed/Feed';

import Search from './components/SearchUser/Search';

import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile';

import Header from './components/Header/Header';

import firebase from './util/firebase';

class App extends Component
 {
 
constructor(){

   super();

   this.state={
     user:'',
     loading: true
   }

 } 


 componentDidMount(){
     
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      this.setState({
        user:user,
        loading: false
      })
      // ...
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
      // ...
    }
  });
 }
  
  render(){

    const {user, loading}=this.state;

    console.log(user);

    if(loading) return <div>loading...</div>

    return(

      <div>
          {
           user?(
             <Router>
               <Header/>
                <Switch>
                   <Route exact path="/feed">
                       <Feed user={user}/>
                   </Route>
                   <Route path="/search">
                       <Search/>
                   </Route>
                   <Route path="/profile">
                       <Profile/>
                   </Route>
                </Switch>
             </Router>
           ):(
             <SignUp/>
           )
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```